# How to get TopLeft, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomRight, and CentreTop position of Canvas Rect

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Basically, I am trying to get the TopLeft, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomRight, and TopMiddle positions for my rect that has been added to the canvas. Please show me in such a way that it applies to any size change that may occur to the rect. Not for the current specific size.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
ctx.stroke();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need can be calculated using [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) and the drawing information of rect relative to the canvas.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();

var rectLeft = 20;
var rectTop = 20;
var rectRight = 150;
var rectBottom = 100;

ctx.rect(rectLeft, rectTop, rectRight, rectBottom);
ctx.stroke();

var boundingRect = c.getBoundingClientRect();

//TopLeft, TopRight, BottomLeft, BottomRight, and TopMiddle
console.log("TopLeft", `(${boundingRect.top + rectTop},${boundingRect.left + rectLeft})`)
console.log("TopRight", `(${boundingRect.top + rectTop},${boundingRect.left + rectRight})`)
console.log("BottomLeft", `(${boundingRect.top + rectBottom},${boundingRect.left + rectLeft})`)
console.log("BottomRight", `(${boundingRect.top + rectBottom},${boundingRect.left + rectRight})`)
console.log("TopMiddle", `(${boundingRect.top + rectTop},${boundingRect.left + (rectLeft + rectRight)/2})`)
//console.log(boundingRect)
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

[image]

Comment: Issue is, this only gets the bounding client for the canvas, how would I apply this to my rect and get the TopLeft, etc.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to measure the coordinates of drawing rect. But you can calculate it easily using this information.

Comment: How would I do it this with information, also is it possible to do with the width and height?

Comment: @billy, updated the answer which gives the positions of the rect in canvas in viewport size.